# EWS Not Deployed reported by Skype for business while Exchange 2010 and 2016 coexistence

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016, lync-2013

We have Exchange 2010 and Lync 2013 servers in our environment.We are in the middle of Exchange migration to 2016 version.I've installed new servers and set the virtual directories on them.All the urls set correctly.
On some clients I've added mail.mydomain with new server IP address into hosts file to test the new server client access role.Outlook and owa are working fine.Some users have no problem with lync or SFB client but most of them have "EWS Not Deployed" in their lync configuration information and their conversation won't save in conversation history.I try lots of googled solutions but nothing works.Users who don't have any error in their lync have a log in iis like this:

```
/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml &CorrelationID=<empty>;&cafeReqId=d8477152-1642-4a6d-bac0-d224361d42f4; 443 domain\user 172.17.8.202 Microsoft+Office/16.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Microsoft+Outlook+16.0.4549;+Pro) - 200 0 0 135
```

Others who encounter error have below log:

```
/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc &CorrelationID=<empty>;&cafeReqId=14b89ba7-d59a-4c94-8f36-0e8413843a53; 443 domain\username 172.17.8.80 OC/15.0.4997.1000+(Microsoft+Lync) - 302 0 0 27
```

Update:Users whose mailbox are in mailbox 2016 doesn't have such problem and only mailboxes from 2010 have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of 2010 mailboxes already has problems with EWS in lync without moving to 2016 servers but some don't.Moving mailboxes to 2016 servers solve the second group problem but not the first group.The first group problem maybe solve by using client side solution [here](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=rppdWvKuG4rZwQLhu5aADg&q=Exit%20Lync%20Client%20Backup%20your%20old%20%E2%80%9CConversation%20History%E2%80%9D%20folder%20contains%20in%20Outlook%20%28export%20it%20to%20a%20file%29%20Delete%20the%20%E2%80%9CConversation%20History%E2%80%9D%20folder%20and%20close%20%E2%80%9Coutlook%E2%80%9D%20Make%20sure%20that%20Lync%20and%20outlook%20are%20completely%20closed%20and%20no%20processes%20are%20running%20in%20the%20Task%20Manager%20Start%20%E2%80%9Crun%E2%80%9D%20and%20type%20in%20outlook%20%2Fresetfolders%20Start%20Lync%2C%20and%20test%20%28wait%2010%20minutes%20for%20the%20folder%20to%20start%20saving%29%20%20&oq=Exit%20Lync%20Client%20Backup%20your%20old%20%E2%80%9CConversation%20History%E2%80%9D%20folder%20contains%20in%20Outlook%20%28export%20it%20to%20a%20file%29%20Delete%20the%20%E2%80%9CConversation%20History%E2%80%9D%20folder%20and%20close%20%E2%80%9Coutlook%E2%80%9D%20Make%20sure%20that%20Lync%20and%20outlook%20are%20completely%20closed%20and%20no%20processes%20are%20running%20in%20the%20Task%20Manager%20Start%20%E2%80%9Crun%E2%80%9D%20and%20type%20in%20outlook%20%2Fresetfolders%20Start%20Lync%2C%20and%20test%20%28wait%2010%20minutes%20for%20the%20folder%20to%20start%20saving%29%20%20&gs_l=psy-ab.12...363.363.0.1580.2.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..2.0.0.0...0.QZibVw9Bu4k)

Answer (score 1):

As we known, the Lync / SfB client will not use Active Directory SCP records to retrieve the Autodiscover URL. It will **only** use the **DNS-record method**.

Therefore, please ensure point **autodiscover record** (also other Exchange services, for example EWS, OAB) to new Exchange 2013 server. It will do proxy if mailbox in Exchange 2010.

Comment: I already have changed virtual directories of exchange services but we are in a large environment with too many users so I prefer to be sure that everything would be okay before cutting the whole name space by changing dns record of forest.

Comment: All right, however Lync/SFB client only use Autodiscover's DNS record to get EWS service. You can double check it after change this record after everything is fine to migration.

Comment: I correct my question.I add mail and autodiscover address and  new server ip address to hosts file .